# Why do you have to close the body of a request once you have inspected it?

Tags: go

I have seen several examples where you read from `r.Body` and then do a defer `r.Body.Close()` right after. What will happen if we do not close it?

Lets say I have a `http.Handler` and inside it I decode the contents of r.Body like this:

```
func createFeedback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // ... Some code ...
    f := feedback.New()
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(f); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()
    // ... Some more code ...
}
```

Why do we have to close `r.Body`?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a duplicate. The other SO post is about closing response body. This questions is about request body.

Comment: As official documentation (https://pkg.go.dev/net/http?tab=doc#Request) applies, you don't have to. The server will do it by itself. And I strongly agree w/ @discoverAnkit. It's not a duplicate

Comment: this is because is an io.Writer and needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

This is done to prevent resource leak of connections. There goes a phrase in the official go documentation:

https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client

> If the Body is not both read to EOF and closed, the Client's
> underlying RoundTripper (typically Transport) may not be able to
> re-use a persistent TCP connection to the server for a subsequent
> "keep-alive" request.

Comment: Your answer is for the client. The question is for the server.